# How to remove ZoneId?

Tags: jackson, timezone, java-time, zoneddatetime

Thank you always for your help.

I got a problem in my project.

I want to delete Zoned Id and leave only time.

How to remove zoned Id?

It is written using kotlin in Spring Boot Framework.

```java
data class AvailableScheduleRequest (
    val address: String,
    val date: LocalDate,
    val people: Long,
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", timezone = "Asia/Seoul")
    val hour: ZonedDateTime
)
```

```java
@RestController
class Controller(
    val newBookingElasticSearchService: NewBookingElasticSearchService
) {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    fun get(@RequestBody param: Map<String, Any>): List<AvailableRestaurant> {
        val json = JacksonUtils.om.writeValueAsString(param)
        val availableScheduleRequest =
            JacksonUtils.om.readValue(json, AvailableScheduleRequest::class.java)

        println(availableScheduleRequest.hour)
    }
}
```

```java
object JacksonUtils {
    val om = ObjectMapper()

    init {
        val module = SimpleModule()
        module.addDeserializer(String::class.java, JsonRawValueDeserializer.INSTANCE)
        om.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        om.registerModule(KotlinModule())
        om.registerModule(module)
        om.dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
        om.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault())
        om.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
        om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        om.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true)
        om.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true)
        om.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true)
    }
```

This code outputs:

```
2019-10-02T07:00+09:00[Asia/Seoul]
```

But I wanna get this:

```
2019-10-02T07:00+09:00
```

How to get this?

Thank you for your efforts all the time!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), you could use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

Answer (score 0):

The person above answered well, but to answer in more detail, I did the following.

```
zonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime().toZonedDateTime()
```

I hope it helps you. Thanks.